# Call to a member function connection() on null error in Slim using Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, slim

I'm trying to make use of Laravel's Eloquent ORM on Slim microframework, but I've been seeing the error: Call to a member function connection() on null

Here is the code:

**dependency.php**

```
$container['db'] = function($container) {
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($container->get('settings')['database']);

    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;
};
```

**User.php (Model class)**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class User extends Model {

    protected $table = "users";

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
}
```

**HomeController.php (Controller class)**

```
class Home extends Controller {

public function index($request, $response, $args) {
        $user = User::find(1);
        var_dump($user);
        die();
        $title = "Slim Auth";
        $response = $this->view->render($response, 'home.php', ["title" => $title]);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

dependency.php was required into my bootstrap.php file where the Slim class was instantiated thus:

```
$config = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,

        'view' => [
            'view_path' => APP_PATH . 'views/'
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'tutorial_slim_auth',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'passw0rd',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ],
    ]
];

$app = new Slim\App($config);
```

while HomeController.php and User.php were autoloaded via composer json file. After running the index.php (which also included my bootstrap.php) file containing:

```
$app->run();
```

this gave me a fatal error:  Call to a member function connection() on null.
But doing this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($container['db']);
echo '</pre>';
```

in my bootstrap file produced the expected result along with the result of the var_dump function called in the HomeController.php file. What do I do? Or is there anything I'm not doing right?

Comment: an off context question, Why not use lumen, which is a microframework, and supports Eloquent ORM?

Comment: Can you please add the full stack of the exception?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your global $capsule encapsulated here:

```
$container['db'] = function($container) {
    $capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
    $capsule->addConnection($container->get('settings')['database']);

    $capsule->setAsGlobal();
    $capsule->bootEloquent();

    return $capsule;
};
```

Try this:

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection($container['settings']['db']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$container['db'] = function ($container) use ($capsule) {
    return $capsule;
};
```

The reason the first version does not work is that the function is only called if you actually use the capsule, i.e., `$this->db`. No call is made, if you only use an Eloquent model class.

Comment: Any idea why this works? I had the exact same issue.

Comment: How do you add one more connection to another database? How do you tell when you want to use one of those two connections when making a query by using a query builder?

Comment: Perfect. Can you please explain a little more why this works?

Answer (score 0):

On multiple connection , try this:

```
$dbconfig = $ci->settings['db'];

$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;

foreach ($dbconfig['connections'] as $cname => $connection)
{
    $cname = $cname == $dbconfig['default'] ? 'default' : $cname;

    $capsule->addConnection($connection, $cname);
}

$capsule->setFetchMode($dbconfig['fetch']);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$ci['db'] = function ($ci) use($capsule) {
    return $capsule;
};
```

then

```
DB::connection('other_connection')->table('...')->get();
```